# How to find $f(1)+2f(2)+...+nf(n)+...$ if $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)+... =0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^∞{f(n)} = 0$.

Is there any way to calculate the  sum $\sum_{n=1}^∞{nf(n)}$?

Comment: No, in general.

Comment: Surely if $f(n)=1/n^2$, then the initial assumption does not hold (since the sum is equal to one sixth pi squared, not 0), so this function does not fit the criteria.

Comment: My bad. Let's use $f(n) = 1/n^2 - (\pi^2/12)(1/2)^n$ then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *all* you know about the sequence $f(1),f(2),f(3),\ldots$ is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=0$, then it's not possible to say *anything* about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nf(n)$.  For example, if $S$ is any real number, you can have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nf(n)=S$ from the sequence $-S,S,0,0,0,0,\ldots$.

In somewhat greater generality, if $f(2k-1)=-a_k$ and $f(2k)=a_k$ where $a_k\to0$ as $k\to\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=-a_1+a_1-a_2+a_2-a_3+\cdots=0$ while

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nf(n)=-1_1+2a_1-3a_2+4a_2-5a_3+6a_3-7a_4+\cdots=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$

and it's well known that a series can do pretty much anything it likes, even if its terms are tending to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us define (for $n \geq 1,\ m\geq 1$)
$$f_m(n) = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{n-1} & \text{if } n \leq m \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_2(n) = 0\hspace{1cm}  \sum_{n=1}^\infty nf_2(n) = -1$$ but
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_4(n) = 0\hspace{1cm} \sum_{n=1}^\infty nf_4(n) = -2$$
So you cannot uniquely determine the value of your sum based on the assumption.